# How do you program a television

Tags: language-agnostic, operating-system, hardware, volume, television

I have been searching for the major programming language of televisions to no avail.
I want to make a simple program for a television (any brand would make me happy) to display things, control the volumn, change input. I know televisions come with sufficient programs but I want to make my own. Is it a lower language like assembly, or HDL?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

If its not likely to get the original programming information can someone point me in the direction to output television processes for evaluation? I would like to atleast take the television processes and dublicate them so I can possibly edit and override them into a different computing device.

Comment: I would suspect that consumer television designs are proprietary. So you're not likely to find information online unless an employee of said television manufacturer becomes renegade and violates their trust with their employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an LG TV with a serial port on the back (yes, really!), and documentation for using it (for changing the channel etc) in the PDF manual on the CD.  I also came with a complete set of *printed on A2 paper* schematics.  I admit I was somewhat amazed when I found them in the box!  I've seen nothing like it before or since though :(

I think the answer in general is "no".

Changing channel, volume, could be achieved by emulating the remote-control though - you could ask on [electronics.se](http://electronics./stackexchange.com) for help with that sort of task.

Answer (score 1):

Over the last year or so, TVs have become more flexible to modify and adapt. Many manufacturers have APIs and platforms for creating apps.

Samsung has HTML5 based platforms like Tizen and Toast. See their [developer website](http://www.samsungdforum.com/).

Some Sony TVs support modified Android apps. [Guide here](https://developer.sony.com/develop/tvs/android-tv/get-started/). See also WebOS TV and NetCast from [LG](http://developer.lge.com/main/Intro.dev).

Some broadcasters even have released platforms to allow you to target multiple devices - check out BBC's [TV Application Layer (TAL)](http://fmtvp.github.io/tal/getting-started/introducing-tal.html).

Happy hacking!

Comment: This is helpful, seems possible to build an app that handles communication to an external device. Got my wheels turning.